# Turning on email notifications breaks MS Release Management

Tags: deployment, tfs, build, release-management, ms-release-management

I am running TFS 2013 Update 4, Release Management Client Update 4, Release Management Server Update 4, and Update 4 Deployment Agents. I am using ReleaseTfvcTemplate.12.xml.

When a developer checks in code, TFS Build compiles the code, and if it completes then it is released to the DEV stage. This works fine.
However, turning on emails creates a problem.

Let's say I need to notify 10 people of a deployment and then send those same 10 people "approval" emails after the deployment is accepted, which it automatically is. That's 20 emails.

I turned on verbose logging on the RM server and I see that each email takes 30 seconds to send. They send one at a time, one after the other. So it takes ten minutes to send twenty emails.

The emails start sending as soon as the deployment starts. The actual deployment usually takes around 1 minute. Release Management marks the build as deployed and keeps sending the "deploying" and "approval" emails. Meanwhile the TFS Build Configuration log is stuck waiting at:

Process each ConfigurationsToRelease
Release the build
Run the Release Management build process for the current configruation

If a deployment finishes its' emails because they are turned off or there are only 3-4 to send, then the TFS Build Configuration log completes the release and the build is marked successful. However, TFSBuild will only wait 5 minutes at the "Release the build" part of the ReleaseTfvcTemplate workflow. If it takes longer than 5 minutes to send 20 emails, which it does, the build fails. How do I increase this timeout? I have upped the timeout on every component/tool I could find in Release Management. I even changed some web.config timeout settings.

The end result is I end up with deployed code, Release Management thinks everything went fine, and TFS Build thinks the build failed.

Edit:

Here are some lines I pulled from the verbose RM server logs. Notice the timestamps. (I cut some lines out)

> 7/28/2015 3:49:48 PM - Verbose - (13008, 12024) - A workflow execution
>   is completed. 7/28/2015 3:49:48 PM - Information - (13008, 12024) -
>   DeploymentControllerServiceProcessor.OnActivityComplete: Workflow
>   completed successfully, accept the deployment step. LocalReleaseId:
>   596, LocalReleaseStepId: 2158 7/28/2015 3:54:47 PM - Information -
>   (13008, 6952) -
>   DeploymentControllerServiceProcessor.PrepareNotificationForDeployerImplementation:
>   NextActivityReadyForDeployment:  7/28/2015 3:54:47 PM - Information -
>   (13008, 6952) -
>   DeploymentControllerServiceProcessor.GetNextComponentReadyForDeployment:
>   DeploymentEvent:  7/28/2015 3:54:49 PM - Information - (13008, 12024)
>   - Exception in DeploymentControllerServiceProcessor.OnActivityComplete, app.Completed
>   7/28/2015 3:54:49 PM - Verbose - (13008, 12024) - The request was
>   aborted: The request was canceled.: \r\n\r\n   at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.WebRequest.PlatformHttpClient.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.WebRequest.RestClientResponseRetriever.EndGetAsyncMemoryStreamFromResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, IPlatformHttpClient platformHttpClient)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.WebRequest.RestClientResponseRetriever.EndDownloadString(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, IPlatformHttpClient platformHttpClient)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.WebRequest.RestClient.EndPost(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.Proxy.RestProxy.HttpRequestor.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(String
>   url, String body)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.Proxy.RestProxy.BaseNotificationServiceProxy.SendNotification(Int32
>   releaseId, String releaseName, String applicationVersionName, String
>   stageTypeName, String environmentName, Int32 releaseStepId, Int32
>   releaseStepTypeId, Boolean releaseStepIsAutomated)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Workflow.Services.ReleaseWorkflowService.CreateNextReleaseStep(Release
>   release, Stage stage, StageStep stageStep, Int32 releaseStageRank,
>   Int32 trialNumber)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Workflow.Services.ReleaseWorkflowService.MoveToNextReleaseStep(Release
>   release, Stage currentStage, ReleaseStep currentReleaseStep)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Workflow.Services.ReleaseWorkflowService.MoveWorkflowForward(Release
>   release, ReleasePath releasePath, Stage currentStage, ReleaseStep
>   currentReleaseStep, Int32 lastStepRankOfCurrentStage)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Workflow.Services.ReleaseWorkflowService.AcceptStep(Release
>   release, Int32 releaseStepId, Int32 actualApproverId, String
>   approverComment, Nullable`1 deferredDateTime)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Workflow.Services.ReleaseWorkflowService.CreateNextReleaseStep(Release
>   release, Stage stage, StageStep stageStep, Int32 releaseStageRank,
>   Int32 trialNumber)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Workflow.Services.ReleaseWorkflowService.MoveToNextReleaseStep(Release
>   release, Stage currentStage, ReleaseStep currentReleaseStep)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Workflow.Services.ReleaseWorkflowService.MoveWorkflowForward(Release
>   release, ReleasePath releasePath, Stage currentStage, ReleaseStep
>   currentReleaseStep, Int32 lastStepRankOfCurrentStage)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Workflow.Services.ReleaseWorkflowService.AcceptStep(Release
>   release, Int32 releaseStepId, Int32 actualApproverId, String
>   approverComment, Nullable`1 deferredDateTime)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.ServiceProcessor.Processor.DeploymentControllerServiceProcessor.OnActivityComplete(String
>   workflow, WorkflowApplicationCompletedEventArgs e)

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting on the "Administration" tab under "Settings" for "TFS Trigger Deployment Timeout". If you increase that, the build won't fail after 5 minutes.

I'd invest some time looking at why it takes 30 seconds to send each email, though. I've never seen that particular problem... it could be a network issue, or an issue with your mail server.

Comment: I've set that to 99 as well as every component/tool timeout I could find. I even copied the Microsoft tools I use so I could set their timer myself (they're not editable by default.)

I have no idea why it takes 30 seconds to send an email, but it consistently does. They don't send consecutively either. I checked with our Exchange admins and our email server doesn't seem to be the culprit, but maybe they're mistaken. There's no errors in the Release Management server log about emails being unable to send.

Comment: Here's what I see a lot of in the RM server logs when it comes to emails (note the time stamps):

"7/28/2015 3:44:46 PM - Verbose - (13008, 7140) - A notification titled Release Management Server – Deployment in Progress (domain\account) will be sent to user with email account@domain.com"

"7/28/2015 3:45:16 PM - Verbose - (13008, 7140) - A notification titled Release Management Server – Deployment in Progress (domain\account) was sent to user with email account@domain.com"

Comment: If something (like Exchange throttling or our spam filter) is preventing the emails from sending faster I don’t see any indication of that in the RM server logs.

Comment: How about using [Papercut](https://papercut.codeplex.com/) to temporarily bypass your Exchange server to rule it out?

Comment: I did not know Papercut existed. Thank you. That's a great idea. I'll come back with an update tomorrow.

Edit: I guess I'd still need to use the Exchange server to send the email though.